# Android: How to call a function with the same name from different classes WITHOUT using switch statements?

Tags: java, android, function, class, methods

I'm relatively new to java +/- android coding (old C++ coder). I'm building an app where users can work through different Cases using a similar interface. The answers / functions / inner workings / numbers will be different based on case.

Example:
I have a VitalsDisplay activity which is supposed to be the generic vitals display code. It wants to use a function - SetVitals(Vitals) - to modify the string array Vitals before displaying the vitals.

SetVitals has to be "smart" - based on which case I'm working on (int CaseNumber, a public int defined in the MainActivity) it will modify the vitals array in different ways. Now, the simple way to define SetVitals would be:

```
public static string[] SetVitals(String[] givenVitals){

  switch (MainActivity.CaseNumber){
    case 1: 
      //Change vitals in one way
      break;
    case 2:
      //Change Vitals in another way
      break;

  }
}
```

*I don't want to do it this way* because I'm worried about scaling in the future - if I want to add extra cases for example, I'd have to hunt and peck through this code to make changes. Furthermore, each case will need to do more than just set vitals (you'll order tests etc, which will have to return different results based on the case). So expanding this in the future would mean I'd have to hunt and peck through Vitals, Results, Tests functions etc.

Instead, I was hoping to define multiple activities:

ChestPain1, ChestPain2, and ChestPain3 for example. Each has an instance of SetVitals(string array Vitals). They would also have instances of OrderResults, CaseUpdates etc. that can be called by the main activity.

The problem with this method is two fold:

1. Now the switch statement gets moved to the VitalsDisplay activity/function. This itself isn't bad - there'll need to be a switch statement at SOME point to decide which function needs to be called based on what Case the user is doing.

**I was wondering if there is a way to NOT have to recreate the switch statement EVERY TIME I need to get Case Specific information from a function in a unique activity (based on CaseNumber)?** I tried to create intents based on a switch statement and then use the intents to call the function... and failed (probably my fault because I'm not great at intent usage yet)

1. I also tried to do this:

   public boolean VitalsDisplay(){
       if (CaseNumber == 1){

   ```
     ChestPain1 CaseInfoToCall = new ChestPain1();

   }

   else if (CaseNumber ==2){

     ChestPain2 CaseInfoToCall = new ChestPain2();

   }

     ClassInfoToCall.SetVitals(array);
   ```

   //Update text fields and display vitals
   }

And **I get an ERROR**: "Duplicate local variable ClassInfoToCall".

**Any ideas on how I can better implement this?**

***Summary***: How can I from one activity call a similarly named function in multiple classes? The decision on which Class to call from will be based off an int variable set in MainActivity.

(Unless someone has a cleaner way to do this - Which I'd totally go for as well!)

Comment: Does there have to be two classes: ChestPain1 and ChestPin2, why not two instances of the same class?

Comment: I saw some information about this when I searched through StackOverflow, but I'm not sure how to set it up (everything I tried failed). Can you give me some examples?

Comment: I guess you're a C# developer but nonetheless please stick to Java's naming convention and start variable names with a lower case letter. ;-)

Comment: Can you show me how you change the caseNumber ? where do you change it ? or where does the user change it ? i think i can help you to avoid the switch

Comment: @coding.mof - whoops. Yes - didn't realize the convention changed! Grumble grumble.

Comment: @YAT : Thanks for offering to help! The caseNumber is set when a user clicks on a button. There are a series of buttons in MainActivity layout - each corresponding to a case (right now I've got 6, so there are 6 buttons). Each has an OnClickListener --> onClick which calls a function SetupAndGo(v, CaseNames, CaseDescs, CaseNumber). SetupAndGo initializes the value of CaseNumber (among other things) based on which button was clicked. Eventually, it calls the VitalsDisplay class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did, hope it fits your need, i did it with 2 cases only, but it's the same thing for more cases :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    CaseWorker worker;


    Button button1;
    Button button2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                worker = new CaseOne();

            }
        });


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                worker = new CaseTwo();

            }
        });

    }

    public void anotherMethod(String[] givenVitals){
       worker.SetVitals(givenVitals);
   }
}
```

Here is the CaseWorker interface, you can add to it other behaviours that are case dependent :

```
public interface CaseWorker {
    public  String[] SetVitals(String[] givenVitals);
}
```

And here are the two implementations corresponding to the two cases  :

```
public class CaseOne implements CaseWorker {

    @Override
    public String[] SetVitals(String[] givenVitals) {
        // do the work the first way
        return null;
    }

}


public class CaseTwo implements CaseWorker {

    @Override
    public String[] SetVitals(String[] givenVitals) {
        // do the work the second way
        return null;
    }

}
```

You can add other buttons, and for each button you add you will have to provide another CaseWorker implementation : CaseThree, CaseFour, ...
No need to switch because you're already doing it by setting the listeners to the differents buttons you have (the switch is already in the UI).

Comment: It's the same answer as @Sarge Borsch  but with the code, hope it's clear for you

Comment: This is amazing thanks so much @YAT! I'm modifying my code to include this stuff and I'm sure it'll work. Follow up question for you (sorry to be a further burden): is there a way to make "worker" public/global? Such that it can be called by different classes? Basically I'm asking if I can just define worker once in MainActivity and then call it in another class w/o having to do a switch class to redefine worker.

Comment: can you tell me exactly from where you want to call the worker ? is it from another activity ? or a class used in the same activity ? tell me what you want to do so that i can give you the best answer i have

Comment: MainActivity class will call the VitalsDisplay class. This will eventually call PatientRoom class. Both these classes will need information from CaseTwo or CaseOne. The button pushing is done in MainActivity, so worker object is created there... but not accessible (I think) by PatientRoom or VitalsDisplay classes. I can make switch statements similar to the button pushing statements in PatientRoom and VitalsDisplay classes to re-create "worker", but I was wondering if there's a "public" way to create worker. Can I do a "public static CaseWorker CaseBridge;" line in the MainActivity class?

Comment: yes if you want you can  make the worker field public static, it will be accessible from everywhere like this : MainActivity.worker  , but this is a bad practice, the worker should normally be accessible only where it's really needed.

Note that the MainActivity is more than a class, it's an Activity, so when you say "the VitalsDisplay class" or "PatientRoom class"  i don't know if you are talking about Activities or normal classes that are called in MainActivity,

Comment: Ah sorry. Still trying to understand terminology. VitalsDisplay and PatientRoom are their own activities just like MainActivity is an activity. I just tried defining it as public-static and it worked! 

And I definitely try to avoid public/global variables as much as possible. This is one of those crucial variables because I don't want to re-create the "switch" code - that way in the future if I add more cases / change cases, I only need to change it in 1 place. Thanks again so much YAT - you're great!

Answer (score 1):

> call the a function with the same name from different classes

You can make that classes implement an interface with method that you want to call. Then you can call it, when you have instance of one of these classes.

#### Update 1

```
interface YourInterface {
    void DoSomething();
}

class A implements YourInterface {
    @Override
    void DoSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

class B implements YourInterface {
    @Override
    void DoSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

// now, somewhere else...

    YourInterface foo =
        someBooleanVariable ?
            new A() :
            new B();
    // we don't know is it an instance of A or B, but corresponding method will be called:
    foo.DoSomething();
```

Sorry if there's an error, I currently have no Java installed...

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to do this? I'm still struggling to understand how some of these things work. Sorry if the request is super basic..

Comment: @KarthikM See update. (Note that it is not complete code, but you can get the idea)

Comment: Sarge this is awesome! You and YAT gave the same answer so I'm guessing this is an important coding lesson I should learn :) Thanks!